# Optimum way to delete selected data from database

Tags: c#, jet

I have a huge database (nearly 7 million records). The schema is some what like this:
`tbl_Info: (ID, Name, ...)`
I have a `ListBox` which contains a number of items which can be related to the Name column of the `tab_Info`. The number of items present in the listbox can be up to few thousands. I want to delete every name contained in the `ListBox` from the database table. I have thought of two ways to do this.

1. Read every item one by one and execute the delete query respectively. I think its a very bad idea.
2. Read the items of ListBox items in bulk and then apply the delete query. I can use loop to read all entries and pass the query like `delete * from tab_Info where Name IN (item1, item2,...,itemN)` . **But this also takes a lot of time to complete.**

What can be done to make it work faster?

Comment: what's the storage eninge type  of `tbl_Info` table?

Comment: **Prepare** a statement once, then **execute** it repeatedly with different **parameters**.  How are you accessing MySQL?

Comment: Actually I am working with Access database so my engine is Microsoft Jet engine.

Comment: I wish I could help if you were using `MySQL` having storage engine 'InnoDb'

Comment: Why is the `Name` in the listbox items not directly associated to the entry `ID`? Are the names taken from somewhere else or is it just an internal logic that is passing the name around on its own? Generally speaking, delete by `ID` should be more efficient unless you have a unique index on `Name`. But I'm not an expert on the details of Access database.

Comment: Every name is unique in the Name field. In my case, Name is used for identification.